# within Array search in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to search in array of `ElasticSearch`. I've documents like

```
{
     "product_name": "iPhone 9",
     "features":[
          {
               "color": "black",
               "memory": "128GB"
          },
          {
               "color": "white",
               "memory": "64GB"
          }
     ],
},
{
     "product_name": "iPhone 9",
     "features":[
          {
               "color": "black",
               "memory": "64GB"
          },
          {
               "color": "white",
               "memory": "64GB"
          }
     ],
}
```

I want to search `iphone 9` with `color = black` and `memory = 64GB`. I'm using following query

```
_search?q=product_name:"iPhone 9"+AND+features.color:"black"+AND+features.memory:"64GB"
```

Only the second record from the document should get listed, but this query is displaying both the records as it matches `color` with first array and `memory` with second array. How can I achieve the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch has no concept of inner objects. Therefore, it flattens object hierarchies into a simple list of field names and values.

Your document will be transformed internally and stored as

```
{
  "product_name" :        "iPhone 9",
  "features.color" : [ "black", "white" ],
  "features.memory" :  [ "128GB", "64GB" ]
}
```

The associate between color and memory is lost.

If you need to maintain independence of each inner object of array , you need to use [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

Nested type can be only queried using [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

```
PUT index-name
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "features": {
        "type": "nested" 
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT index-name/_doc/1
{
     "product_name": "iPhone 9",
     "features":[
          {
               "color": "black",
               "memory": "128GB"
          },
          {
               "color": "white",
               "memory": "64GB"
          }
     ],
}

GET index-name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "features",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "features.color": "black" }},
            { "match": { "features.memory":  "64GB" }} 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Glad could be of help